# BIP0034 block height using python-bitcoinlib

Tags: script, coinbase-transaction, programming-bitcoin-book

I'm doing some experiments for finding coinbase height from freshly mined block which is received from ZMQ.

```
    tx_coinbase = CTransaction.deserialize(x('010000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff2303f90d1800fe6d8a0300fea00a04000963676d696e6572343208010000000000000000ffffffff02bc078402000000001976a914c11998cf0635b9ba940212af99447dfbdcfafe9688ac0000000000000000266a24aa21a9ed7a0ea91535f513cc527e1858a43800c2f6712d45404877f59f564a8eea88276f0120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'))
    scriptSig = tx_coinbase.vin[0].scriptSig
    coinbase_script = CScript(scriptSig)
    for o in coinbase_script:
        h = int(b2lx(o), 16)
        logging.debug(h)
        break
```

It is really weird in my opinion. The question:

Is there better solution to parse `scriptSig` and pull block height?

*It is also an exercise 2 from 'Programming Bitcoin' Chapter 9. But I really want to get block height using only raw block obtained from Core via zmq.